# "British" sounds "brish", is this a glottal stop or just the presenter's accent?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, glottal-stop

Americans uses [glottal stop](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/7500/108307) in spoken English.

It sounds like the video is [saying](https://youtu.be/NHTJPd7cnBU) (a video link with a time stamp)

> **British** explorer Bear Grylls is best known to TV audiences for Discovery's Man vs. Wild

where "British" sounds "brish", is this a glottal stop or just the presenter's accent?

Comment: I hear a normal American flap for the /t/.

Comment: This is a feature of Australian English too. We often delete or replace the /t/ sound, just like speakers with an American accent (like the narrator here). So it sounds (to me) more like “Bridish” than “Brish”. I regard it as very standard pronunciation rather than heavily accented. This is one of the features of Australian English discussed here: https://thevoicescience.com/australian-accent/